# Fide Rating result

Tags: rating, fide

In JUly, 2015 I got 1.5 points against rated player and faced 6 players  and again in January, 2016 I faced three more fide rated players . Totally, I faced 9 fide rated players, Shall I eligible for fide rating?

Answer (score 1):

[FIDE Rating Regulations effective from 1 July 2014](https://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=172&view=article)

> 7.1
>
> On the first day of each month, the QC shall prepare a list which
>   incorporates the rated play during the rating period into the previous
>   list. This shall be done using the rating system formula.
>
> 7.11
>
> The rating period (for new players, see 7.14) is the period where a
>   certain rating list is valid.
>
> 7.12
>
> The following data will be kept concerning each player whose rating is
>   at least 1000 as of the current list: FIDE title, Federation, Current
>   Rating, FIDE ID Number, Number of Games rated in the rating period,
>   Date of Birth, Gender and the current value of K for the player.
>
> 7.13
>
> The closing date for tournaments for a list is 3 days before the date
>   of the list; tournaments ending before or on that day may be rated on
>   the list. Official FIDE events may be rated on the list even if they
>   end on the last day before the list date.
>
> 7.14
>
> A rating for a player new to the list shall be published only if it
>   meets the following criteria:
>
> 7.14a
>
> If based on results obtained under 6.2, a minimum of 5 games.
>
> 7.14b
>
> If based on results obtained under 6.3, a minimum of 5 games played
>   against rated opponents.
>
> 7.14c
>
> The condition of a minimum of 5 games need not be met in one
>   tournament. Results from other tournaments played within consecutive
>   rating periods totalling not more than 26 months, are pooled to obtain
>   the initial rating.
>
> 7.14d
>
> The rating is at least 1000.
>
> 7.14e
>
> The rating is calculated using all his results as if they were played
>   in one tournament (it is not published until he has played at least 5
>   games) by using all the rating data available.

Yes you are eligible.